# Updating MySQL fields in a PHP FOR loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a a series of columns in a MySQL table (check1, check2, check3, etc.) that are set to either 0 or 1, depending on whether their corresponding fields in a PHP form are empty (sig1, sig2, sig3, etc). For example, if a field (sig1) is NOT empty, then its corresponding column (check1) is set to 1. I have fifteen such fields, and I was wondering if there was a way to set the columns to their correct values in a loop. I know I can write my PHP like this to loop through the form fields themselves:

```
for($i=1; $i<=15; i++) {
 if(!empty($_POST['sig'.$i]) {
   //Update corresponding MySQL check column
   }
 }
```

What I can't figure out is how to tell the database which check column to update. Is there a way to make the loop differentiate between check1, check2, etc.?

Comment: Why wouldn't you update all columns with a single UPDATE statement when the form is submitted?

Comment: `empty('string')` will NEVER be true. Likewise `!empty('string')` will NEVER be false. Are these variables? (`$sig1`, `$sig2` etc.)?

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Yes, $sig* are POST variables from the form, and each has a corresponding flag in the database (check*). The flag should be set to 1 if the field is not empty. The POST vars are signature lines, so the db update should only happen if a new signature is added. A for loop *seemed* to be the best way to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could update all 15 of them *individually*:

```
for($i=1; $i<=15; i++)
{
    mysqli_query("UPDATE table SET check" . $i . " = " .
                    (empty($_POST['sig' . $i]) ? "0" : "1"));
}
```

**But please don't do this!** You can update them all at once with a single query (more efficient):

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET ";
for($i=1; $i<=15; i++)
{
    if($i > 1) { $query .= ", "; }
    $query .= "check" . $i . " = " . (empty($_POST['sig' . $i]) ? "0" : "1"));
}
mysqli_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

`!empty('sig'.$i)` will never be false. You are missing `$`. Try this:

```
for($i=1; $i<=15; i++) {
  if(!empty($_POST['sig'.$i]) {
    //Update corresponding MySQL check column
  }
}
```

If you dont want use $_POST (have globals on):

```
for($i=1; $i<=15; i++) {
  if(!empty(${'sig'.$i}) {
    //Update corresponding MySQL check column
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I left $_POST out for brevity. It is actually a part of my condition. :-)